# (OS X) Port in use, however it is not shown by netstat or lsof

Tags: macos, networking

Sorry for my english.
I was trying to forward port 80 from my vagrant box to host machine (OS X) and got this message

> "The forwarded port to 80 is already in use on the host machine."

So, in order to figure out which program uses port 80 i ran this:

```
➜  ~  sudo lsof -n -i:80 | grep LISTEN
➜  ~
```

However, as you can see, it shows nothing.I have also tried netstat, but result was the same. Then i tried to use netcat + tcpdump to look at tcp session:

```
➜  ~  nc -vvv 127.0.0.1 80
Connection to 127.0.0.1 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
➜  ~

In another window:

➜  ~  sudo tcpdump  -ni lo0 port 80
Password:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo0, link-type NULL (BSD loopback), capture size 65535 bytes
    00:03:47.019805 IP 127.0.0.1.50666 > 127.0.0.1.80: Flags [S], seq 2187569264, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 194193524 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    00:03:47.019834 IP 127.0.0.1.80 > 127.0.0.1.50666: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2187569265, win 0, length 0
```

So it looks like the port is closed, because it immediately sent RESET flag, but why did nc show that connection was successful and lsof show nothing.
I'm really confused. Can anyone tell me what is going on, or what am i doing wrong?
I can provide additional information if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Try just doing `lsof -n -i :80` or `lsof -i -n -P | grep :80`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that's firewall reset connection.
Turn off Avast WebShield if it exists.

Comment: Thanks, that was the case.